# Need to add index to left join

Tags: sql, indexing

I am trying to optimize the query below. Unfortunately, I do not have permissions to view the query optimization plan. My initial though is to add index to the left outer join. I have tried creating indexes and forcing but have not had any luck with the proper syntax or placement. Here is the code I am using.

```
select x.*
into #info_set
from (select *,
             case when rev.is_re > 0 then 1 else null end as is_re,
             case when rev.is_os > 0 then 1 else null end as is_os,
             case when rev.is_pac > 0 then 1 else null end as is_pac
      from edtomic.dbo.info cc left outer join 
           (select cd.id,
                   sum(case when cd.code = '0452' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by cd.id) as is_re,
                   sum(case when cd.code = '0760' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by cd.Id) as is_os,
                   sum(case when cd.Code = '0021' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by cd.id) as is_pac,
                  row_number() over (partition by cd.Id order by (select 0)) as seq
            from edtomic.dbo.infodetail cd 
            where cd.Flag = 'n'

           ) rev
          on rev.id = cc.Id and rev.seq = 1 
      where cc.Flag = 'n' and
            cc.Status_Code = 'hrd1' and
            cc.Data_Source = 'aki' and
            cc.type = 'hjak'

) x;
```

Comment: What does `order by (select 0)` do for you?

Comment: Seems like a compound index on `id, code` _might_ help, but it all depends on how the analyzer chooses to create the plan. What makes you think the left join (or the subquery) is the bottleneck?

Comment: That said, I think you can reorganize the query and maybe get better performance.  You aren't using the counts (just checking if it's > 0), so an EXISTS might be better.

Comment: Like @DStanley is mentioning, I don't see what that order by is doing for you. Are you getting a random row? If so, why only join off the first row? I think you're query is flawed. Are you trying to get every edtomic.dbo.info and if it has those three codes?

Comment: To be honest I inherited the query from another person so I am not sure what the order by (select 0) is used for. How/where would I add a compound index on id, code?

Comment: I am open to any suggestions or recommendations.

Comment: @ollyjolly OK, so we would need to know what it is supposed to be doing and ideally we'd get some test data with expected results.

Comment: @ollyjolly:please post execution plan as xml

Answer (score 1):

Based on what it looks like it is trying to do, I think this would be fast. You should be able to copy the bottom most SELECT and rename the table variables into your actual tables. If it is still slow, I recommend ensuring there are indexes on the ID columns on both tables as  well as Flag.

```
DECLARE @edtomic_dbo_info TABLE (
    ID INT,
    Flag VARCHAR(20),
    Status_Code VARCHAR(20),
    Data_Source VARCHAR(20),
    type VARCHAR(20)
)

DECLARE @edtomic_dbo_infodetail TABLE (
    ID INT,
    code VARCHAR(20),
    Flag VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @edtomic_dbo_info
    SELECT 1 AS ID,'n' AS Flag,'hrd1' AS Status_Code,'aki' AS Data_Source,'hjak' AS type
INSERT INTO @edtomic_dbo_info
    SELECT 2 AS ID,'n' AS Flag,'hrd1' AS Status_Code,'aki' AS Data_Source,'hjak' AS type

INSERT INTO @edtomic_dbo_infodetail SELECT 1 AS ID,'xxxx' AS code,'n' AS Flag
INSERT INTO @edtomic_dbo_infodetail SELECT 1 AS ID,'0452' AS code,'n' AS Flag
INSERT INTO @edtomic_dbo_infodetail SELECT 1 AS ID,'0452' AS code,'n' AS Flag
INSERT INTO @edtomic_dbo_infodetail SELECT 1 AS ID,'xxxx' AS code,'n' AS Flag
INSERT INTO @edtomic_dbo_infodetail SELECT 1 AS ID,'0021' AS code,'n' AS Flag
INSERT INTO @edtomic_dbo_infodetail SELECT 2 AS ID,'xxxx' AS code,'n' AS Flag
INSERT INTO @edtomic_dbo_infodetail SELECT 2 AS ID,'0452' AS code,'n' AS Flag

select
    cc.ID,
    CONVERT(BIT,sum(case when id.code = '0452' then 1 else 0 end)) as is_re,
    CONVERT(BIT,sum(case when id.code = '0760' then 1 else 0 end)) as is_os,
    CONVERT(BIT,sum(case when id.code = '0021' then 1 else 0 end)) as is_pac
from @edtomic_dbo_info cc
LEFT JOIN @edtomic_dbo_infodetail id ON id.id = cc.Id
    AND id.Flag = 'n'
where cc.Flag = 'n' and
cc.Status_Code = 'hrd1' and
cc.Data_Source = 'aki' and
cc.type = 'hjak'
GROUP BY cc.id
```

Comment: Thank you Ghost. I will try that.

Comment: If I need to add an index for ID and flag where would I add them?

Comment: @ollyjolly To both tables if they are missing.

Comment: So they need to be added to the table versus the query?

Comment: @ollyjolly Yes, if they are missing. As you seem unfamiliar, you should find out exactly what indexes are present on the table and really understand this before simply adding them.

Comment: ok thank you. I do believe I have the ability to add indexes directly on the tables. I was thinking I could add something like this to the query. CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX indx_id ON rev (id)

Comment: I tried to copy the select you provided to no avail. In addition to the fields in the SELECT I had to add a Case When with a sub select. Which could not be added under the GROUP BY so unfortunately it would not work.

Comment: @ollyjolly the above SQL runs fine for me, so saying it would not work doesn't help. You need to explain what errors you are getting.

Comment: I attempted to add the following case when to the SELECT statement, but I am unable to add to the group by 
 , case when cc._type like '11%' 
   and exists (
   select null
   from edtomic.dbo.info_detail cd
   where cd.id = cc.id
    and cd.soft_flag = 'n'
    and cd.ser_code = '0024'
     ) then 1 else null end as is_stype

Comment: @ollyjolly If you take the select above and simply fix the table names to be correct, does it run for you?

Comment: Yes it does run.

Comment: @ollyjolly So, it sounds like you have another question to ask as to what is wrong with your new, updated SQL :)